# Quantum Field Theory on non-globally hyperbolic spacetimes?

Tags: spacetime, resource-recommendations, causality, topology, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In all the references I have found on QFT in curved spacetime, they treat only globally hyperbolic Lorentzian spacetimes, not Lorentzian spacetimes in general. Are there any references which discuss QFT in general Lorentzian spacetimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty in doing QFT on non-globally hyperbolic spacetimes is that, because there is no Cauchy surface, there is prima facie no (well motivated) way to define the canonical commutation relations. Therefore, any attempt to formulate a QFT on such a spacetime must impose some sort of condition to ensure the spacetime is locally well-behaved. Two classic formulations are being Yurtsever (1994)(https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/11/4/016) and Kay (1992) (https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0129055X92000194). The former postulates 'micro-causality', and the latter 'F-locality' to ensure the QFT is locally well-behaved.

A related reference is Deutsch (1991) (https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.44.3197); but I haven't read this yet, and it is in a quantum info, not QFT framework, so may be tangential to your interests.

Comment: Can we not get around this by using path integrals?

Comment: I don't know about path-integrals in curved spacetimes so am not the best person to answer your question, but I am not sure how you imagine path integrals would help. Maybe you can say more? An initial problem I see will be that a non-globally hyperbolic spacetime will not admit a foliation in Cauchy surfaces, so you cannot expect to have any sort of well-defined 'time'-slices over which to perform an integral.